# Locate UserControl from Shell Window when using View Model First (DataTemplate) in WPF

Tags: wpf, window, datatemplate

I'm loading UserControl(s) into a shell window using DataTemplate(s) (View Model First).
How can I get a reference to the UserControl that is currently contained in that Window?

Comment: Why do you need the UserControl and not the ViewModel?

Comment: when you do View Model First then you load a viewmodel(not a usercontrol) and bind it to a contentcontrol.content property. wpf do the rest and search for a datatemplate to show you your viewmodel within your usercontrol.

Comment: Why down vote?? 

@ Mark Green: I need a referene to the user control because there's a strictly-UI operation that's need to be done- ONLY in the WPF client.

@blindmeis: I know how things works in View Model First, and I still need to use the current user control.

Comment: even with a datatemplate a usercontrol fires onload event. so who need a reference to the usercontrol?

Comment: @blindmeis: It's not a question of why do I need the reference, or is it MVVM compatible- it's a question of how to get it. onload will not work here.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab current application window:

```
Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

And then you could check its content/children. But that will be breaking MVVM pattern which I guess you are trying to achieve. In cases where you need to hook up something to a usercontrol specific stuff, you should use interaction behaviors.

Comment: No good- those proprties will not give me the current user control. I'm fully aware that this breaks the pattern, but it's not a bad practice in this case- I need to perform a UI operation that's uniqe to the WPF client.